# facebook application FBML: error code 405 when changing app from Iframe to FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml

I'm trying to write a simple facebook application using FBML.

when I configure my application to work as an IFrame and I view the source
i see the following:

```
<html> 
<head> 
</head> 
<body> 
<fb:swf
 swfbgcolor="000000"
 imgstyle="border-width:3px; border-color:white;"
 swfsrc='http://url/file.swf'
 width='340' height='270' /> 
</body> 
</html>
```

When I change my application to be an FBML application i get the following error:

```
Application Temporarily Unavailable
Received HTTP error code 405 while loading http://xpofb.xpogames.com:5080/xpogame-    servlet/Canvas?

Sorry, the application you were using is experiencing a problem. Please try again later.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp... after a lot of research on the internet i read that some people added rewrite rules to /foo will be /foo.html and that would work.

When I tried to add rewrite rules in my case it didn't resolve the issue.
moving from a servlet to a jsp page did resolve the issue.

the Servlet was at url/Canvas

rewriting it to url/Canvas.html did not resolve the issue

creating a new jsp file at url/canvas.jsp resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put just plain text to FBML so you can be sure that it is not some FBML tag that is causing problem.

Facebook may act funny if your Canvas URL doesn't end with a slash. Try to map your controller to a directory and try again.

Also FBML apps don't support `html`, `head`, `body` tags, so that would be your next error message.

Comment: I removed everything, i left only the line 'test' and it acts the same. it fails with the same error code on FBML.